# Boundary/contour tracing of a binary image in Python

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software, percolation

I'm studying percolation on a square lattice. I identify clusters on the binary lattice using the SciPy API ndimage.label. My goal is to study the external perimeter (hull) of each of these clusters. That is, I wish to trace the contour/boundary of a binary image starting at specified pixel. I'm aware of several algorithms for doing so (eg. [Moore](https://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/moore.html) and [Pavlibs](https://www.imageprocessingplace.com/downloads_V3/root_downloads/tutorials/contour_tracing_Abeer_George_Ghuneim/theo.html)). I have searched for implementations of these algorithms in common libraries such as NumPy and SciPy without success. This came as a surprise to me, as contour tracing of a binary image feels like a frequent problem in lots of projects in both physics and image processing.

Are any of you aware of acknowledged libraries or API's that have implementations of contour tracing (preferable starting at a specified boundary pixel). Or do I have to implement it myself?

Whoops.. forget to explicitly mention that I was doing the project in Python 3.

Comment: This question may be too coding-oriented for this site. There might be something useful in skimage, eg https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/edges/plot_contours.html

Comment: *I was doing the project in Python 3.* Seeing how python 2.7 was deprecated and abandoned in 2020, it'd be weird to see a project using it still.